# Eclipse (Helios) fails to load DLL

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, dll, unsatisfiedlinkerror

My Java program fails with the following error on Windows.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no XSvcSocket in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
```

I tried different things like

- adding the location of DLL to system's path env variable
- setting location of DLL explicitly in the program as below

  ```
          String libpath = System.getProperty("java.library.path");
          libpath = "C:\\extlibs;" + libpath;
          System.setProperty("java.library.path", libpath);
          libpath = System.getProperty("java.library.path");
  ```

java.library.path I get see is shown below.

```
"Lib Path: C:\extlibs;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows"
```

The DLL in question is available in "C:\extlibs". Couple of observation are that when I place the  DLL into "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin", my program doesn't crib about the DLL (i.e it loads it) but I have to take care of many other DLLs too.

Can anyone shed some light on this behavior? by the way I am also not able to figure out from where eclipse is picking   C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin and adding to java.library.path? it's not part of system's path environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to add native libraries in eclipse is as shown below. Go to `Properties/Java Build Path/Libraries/Expand the jar file for which you want to add the native library/Select Native Library location/Click Edit/Add the DLL`

[image]